# VB.NET What can I have for daily calendars?

Tags: vb.net, schedule, appointment

In VB.NET (Not ASP.NET) what can I use for a daily calendar. I have done extensive DuckDuckGo and Google search and I have came up with no viable options.

The purpose of the calendar is to create a appointment system with multiple dentists therefore appointments also can run in parallel. However having it in parallel isn't required as I may have the end-use select what dentist the appointment is for (creating a appointment, therefore got to select a date/time).

The project is only a university/college project therefore having it perfect isnt a requirement (but I'd prefer it). I'd use anything, otherwise I'm going to have to use a ListView.

#### Examples

- http://bit.ly/JsVhz1
- http://bit.ly/KkGZ5x

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Monthly Calendar has no interface for selecting time but just the date only. You may need to draw your own calendar by FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind people have already solved this problem... don't reinvent the wheel if possible. If you have some budget, try picking one from [here](http://www.componentsource.com/bestsellers/calendar-schedule/index.html). If not there are a couple of WinForms freeware/open source controls, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38699/A-Professional-Calendar-Agenda-View-That-You-Will#xx3153670xx).

Unless you shell out some money, you'll still have to write the actual scheduling part; these are just display controls.